# Attempt to unlock cordova-ios@3.7.0, which hasn't been locked

Tags: ios, cordova

I've trouble while installing the `Cordova 3.5.0` on **Mac**. It keep giving me message:

```
Error: Attempt to unlock cordova-ios@3.7.0, which hasn't been locked
    at unlock (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/locker.js:44:11)
    at cb (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache/add-named.js:32:5)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache/add-named.js:41:20
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/locker.js:30:7
    at cb (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/lockfile/lockfile.js:149:38)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/lockfile/lockfile.js:177:38
    at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:108:15)
```

I tried to uninstall and install it again, the problem still the same. Can anyone give me solutions? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try it with sudo

```
sudo npm install -g cordova
```

Answer (score 0):

After getting lot's of headache i got solution, its simply add **sudo** command before your command

**sudo cordova platform add ios**